# CSV file formatting problem

Tags: file

there's column value which is 1-6, wherein CSV does auto-format and displays the same as 6-JAN. Any solution to overcome this please?

Thanks, 
Seetharaman.

Comment: This is about a problem with a program, please state which one (is it perhaps Excel?). It is also clearly not programming related and better fit for superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use a text-delimiter such as quotes, i.e. `"1-6"`

Comment: I know in Excel it'd be `'1-6`.

Comment: It's a Pro*C program that writes into CSV.  Tried 'TO_CHAR' in the select statement itself, but even then it formats the '1-6' into '6-JAN' in the CSV.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't depend on the file format your using but on the program that writes and saves the file. So which program are you using for editing the csv file?

Comment: It's a Pro*C program that writes into CSV. Tried 'TO_CHAR' in the select statement itself, but even then it formats the '1-6' into '6-JAN' in the CSV. Any suggestions? - Seetharaman

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to format the cells to Text?

Comment: Thank you everyone...got an alternate.  Have used concat in the select.  I tried the same like <value> || '!'...which was not working when execution...but when went with the keyword...concat...it worked - Seetharaman.